# Как работает свойство left?

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

Как менять значение **left** с интервалом?
Например **left = -800px** , нужно каждые три секунды увеличивать **left** на 260px ,
как правильно прописать свойство в js , у меня получилось так -
`` progressLine.style.left = `${"+" + 200 + "px"}`; ``

Но этот вариант работает только один раз, то-есть он не прибавляет к **left** 200px , а просто меняет 800px на 200px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас синтаксис не совсем верный.
Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
setInterval(() => {
  const { left } = progressLine.style;
  const newLeft = parseInt(left, 10) + 200;
  progressLine.style.left = `${newLeft}px`;
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Проблему уже решил, сделал не через div и разный бред , а через тег progress , он удобнее и более подходит под ситуацию